# About pytorch reduction mean

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, loss

I want use L1loss and BCELoss with reduction='mean' in vae reconstruction loss

but it produce same result for all different input i.e. [result for landmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WhlW.png)

so i use reduction='sum' it produce correct result that different output for different input.

how can i use mean reduction??

```
L1Loss = nn.L1Loss(reduction='mean').to(device)   
BCELoss = nn.BCELoss(reduction='mean').to(device)
kld_criterion = KLDLoss(reduction='mean').to(device)
```

in training

```
rec_m, (rec_f, mean_f, logvar_f), (rec_l, mean_l, logvar_l) = model(origin)

lm_loss = CELoss(rec_l, lm)
f_loss = L1Loss(rec_f, f)
m_loss = CELoss(rec_m, m)
                
lm_kld_loss = kld_criterion(mean_l, logvar_l)
f_kld_loss = kld_criterion(mean_f, logvar_f)
                
loss = 4000*(f_loss + m_loss) + 30 * (lm_kld_loss + f_kld_loss) + 2000 * lm_loss
```

and model code

```
class VAE_NET(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nc=3, ndf=32, nef=32, nz=128, isize=128, device=torch.device("cuda:0"), is_train=True):
        super(VAE_NET, self).__init__()

        self.nz = nz
        # Encoder
        self.l_encoder = Encoder(nc=nc, nef=nef, nz=nz, isize=isize, device=device)
        self.f_encoder = Encoder(nc=nc, nef=nef, nz=nz, isize=isize, device=device)
        
        # Decoder
        self.l_decoder = Decoder(nc=nc, ndf=ndf, nz=nz, isize=isize)
        self.m_decoder = Decoder(nc = nc, ndf = ndf, nz = nz * 2, isize = isize)
        self.f_decoder = Decoder(nc = nc, ndf = ndf, nz = nz * 2, isize = isize)

        if is_train == False:
            for param in self.encoder.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
            for param in self.decoder.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False

    def forward(self, x):
        latent_l, mean_l, logvar_l = self.l_encoder(x)
        latent_f, mean_f, logvar_f = self.f_encoder(x)
        concat_latent = torch.cat((latent_l, latent_f), 1)
        rec_l = self.l_decoder(latent_l)
        rec_m = self.m_decoder(concat_latent)
        rec_f = self.f_decoder(concat_latent)
        return rec_m, (rec_f, mean_f, latent_f), (rec_l, mean_l, latent_l)
```

l is for face landmark

m is for face mask

f is for face part

Answer (score 0):

`reduction='sum'` and `reduction='mean'` differs only by a scalar multiple. There is nothing wrong with your implementation from what I see. If your model only produces correct results with `reduction='sum'`, it is likely that your learning rate is too low (and `sum` makes up for that difference by amplifying the gradient).